# Как преобразовать сжатый блок html-кода в структурированный вид?

Tags: html, sublime-text-3, notepad++

Есть сжатый блок html-кода. Как его преобразовать в структурированный вид в `Sublimtext 3` или `Notepad++`?

Comment: Я пользуюсь http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: [**CodeFormatter**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CodeFormatter) — лучший из beautifier, которые пробовал в Sublime Text. Спасибо.

Comment: установи плагина HTML-CSS-JS Prettify,  горячие клавиши ctrl+ shift+H

Comment: @DiDex, Если пользоваться веб-версией jsbeautifier, это лишние движения: скопировать код → открыть нужную страницу браузера → вставить в веб-форму → скопировать и вставить отформатированный код обратно. Когда можно только нажать один шорткат в Sublime Text. Спасибо.

Comment: @Air, не рекомендовал бы. В этом пакете [**много**](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/issues) багов ([**пример**](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/issues/324)) + разработчик [**не собирается**](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/pull/335) их исправлять, чтобы соответствовать последним версиям jsbeautifer.org. Когда мигрировал на CodeFormatter, проблем стало куда меньше. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, ребята

Comment: @СашаЧерных, благодарю.. Щас гляну, что там по ссылкам... Но я меня за 3-4 года, каких либо  глобальных багов не наблюдал, если честно...

Comment: Если это то, о чём я думаю, то никаких дополнительных плагинов я не устанавливал. В саблайм текст 3 в меню Preferences - Key Bindings в настройках пользователя добавил настройку:
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent" },